# Let $L$ be a probability generator is it true that $L_\epsilon = L (I - \epsilon L)^{-1}$ is also a generator?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

This question is issued from the following exercise in Liggett (Continuous time Markov processes) pg 103

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would like to prove property $(d)$ of exercise 3.23 (b).

Comment: "I can't prove property (d)." But you post a full answer 3 minutes later? What is this game?

Comment: I was showing my attempt... Turns out that the writing it helped me see the way through. I posted the question and provided the full answer to keep the record. This is no game at all.

Comment: Attempts should be included in the question, not posted as answers.

Comment: Yes but then if it was a full solution wouldn't it be strange to post it as an attempt? Maybe that is a question to the Meta SE...   I believe  It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Sure this is allowed (but now you are talking about posting an answer while just before you were mentioning showing one's attempt, make up your mind), and yet your formulation is somewhat creepy.

Comment: I'm working on the same problem right now, but I'm stuck on showing (b). Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 0):

We want to find  $f_n$ a sequence of function such that $\sup_n\| (I - \lambda L_\epsilon)f_n\| < \infty$ and $f_n, g_n$ converge to $1$ pointwise.

We might try the sequence $h_n$ that satisfies property $(d)$ for $L$

so let $v_n = (I - \epsilon L)h_n$.

$v_n \to 1$ pointwise and $\sup_n \|v_n\| < \infty$ then

\begin{align}
w_n = v_n - \lambda L_\epsilon v_n &= v_n - \frac{\lambda}{\epsilon} \epsilon L_\epsilon v_n  = \\
& = v_n - \frac{\lambda}{\epsilon} \big[ (I - \epsilon L)^{-1} v_n - v_n \big] \\
& = v_n - \frac{\lambda}{\epsilon} \big[ h_n - v_n \big] \\
\end{align}

Therefore $w_n$ converges pointwise  to  $1$.  the boundedness of $w_n$ is a consequene of the boundedness of $v_n$ and the operator $L_\epsilon$

Comment: It's funny how you call yourself "you".

Comment: Hehe, It is funny indeed cheers!